# Run C++ application with a custom script in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a custom shell that I can run C++ applications in. I start the shell from a bash prompt and then run my C++ code. I want to emulate this behavior with Eclipse, particularly for debugging. I can't seem to figure this out.

I could write a simple bash script that kicks off the custom shell and runs my application but Eclipse does not let me debug when I do this.

Is there a way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind eclipse can set environment variables for running/debugging job.

If your shell is more complicated than that, please provide more details about your shell.

But I'm not optimistic about it.

Btw, you can always attach an existing process for debugging.